# Negative marginal effects

Tags: probability, stata

I'm using Stata 13.1 on W8.1. I'm trying to estimate marginal effects (-`seqlogitdecomp`-) after -`seqlogit`-. Here the code:

```
seqlogit BMI_P  i.Professione1 cohorte Etarecl i.Sesso, or  ///
   tree(1: 2 3 , 2:3 )                                       ///
    ofinterest(SocialStatus) over(Etarecl)                   ///              
    levels(1=22.5, 2=27.5, 3=33.5)

 seqlogitdecomp,at(Sesso 0 Professione1 8 SocialStatus  0.98 )           ///
  marg                         ///
 overat(Etarecl 0, Etarecl 1, Etarecl 2, Etarecl 3, Etarecl 4, ///
 Etarecl 5, Etarecl 6)  ///
 yline(0) xline(0)   ///
 subtitle("&lt;30" "30-39" "40-49" "50-59"  "60-69"  "70-79" "80&gt;") ///
 eqlabel(`""Overweight" "versus" "Normal""' ///
       `""Obesity" "versus" "Overweight""')
```

Stata produces a graph with negative marginal effects. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that social status has a negative effect on BMI: The larger the status the less overweight a person is. So that seems like a perfectly reasonable result. I suspect you were surprised because odds ratios cannot be negative (a "negative" result is an odds ratio less than 1). However, a marginal effect is the slope so an additive efects size (just like a "normal" linear regression) rather than relative effect size (like an odds ratio).